# Bluetooth Low Energy for Windows 7?

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have to write a Windows C# application that interacts with a Bluetooth Low Energy device. The device only has a Bluetooth Low Energy chip on it. 
From the research I've done, it seems like Windows 8.1 is the earliest version of Windows that supports Bluetooth Low Energy.
Is there a way I can make it work on Windows 7? Is there a recommended library to use for this? Any advice, or has anyone attempted this before?

Answer (score 2):

I used "bleno" with CSR 8510 dongle. It works fine for me.
https://github.com/sandeepmistry/bleno

To be sure that your Bluetooth 4.0 USB Adapter is compatible:
https://github.com/sandeepmistry/node-bluetooth-hci-socket#windows

Comment: Running into the following issue when trying to run it: Error: Cannot find module 'bluetooth-hci-socket'

Comment: Follow the instructions carefully:
https://github.com/sandeepmistry/bleno#windows

Comment: got it to work thx Yura! Is there a way to replace the drivers through code instead of making people download the Zadig tool?